# What are some books for pricing theory with heavy math?

Tags: mathematical-economics, reference-request, price-theory

What are some books for pricing theory with heavy math?

I've finish reading pricing theory by Hirshleifer and another by Lansburg but both are not math intense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Darrel Duffie](https://books.google.com/books/about/Dynamic_Asset_Pricing_Theory.html?id=eBy9QgAACAAJ) is the graduate school standard for asset pricing:

Gary Becker and Milton Friedman also have titles that fall within your prompt and are very accessible given your background